# Converting list result into textbox.Text property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I am making a little word guessing game, and I'd like for the user to be able to guess the words. I have the following code, and it loads words from a text file located at `string filename` into a list box. However, I would like for the words to appear one by one in a textbox. The catch does not throw any errors out at all, the textbox is simply empty. Is this possible and could you show me some code so I can have a play please? Cheers!

I can then hide this word using one textbox, and trigger some code to move onto the next word if the typed word into the second, visible textbox is correct.

```
async private void LoadWords(string filename)
{
    var wordList = new List<String>();
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

    try
    {

        Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        var words = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(sampleFile);

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            wordList.Add(word); 
        } 

        HiddenWordBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, wordList);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageDialog CatchMsg = new MessageDialog(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are expecting `HiddenWordBox` to have the concatenated string of words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me for my stupid question but isn't the following code required for it to be seen?

```
await CatchMsg.ShowAsync();
```

Not necessarily with the await operator.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`HiddenWordBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, wordList);`

To

`HiddenWordBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, wordList.ToArray());`

and the output should be as follows: http://ideone.com/DmFI0Z

(There's no constructor for string.Join involving List)

Comment: The textbox is still empty. Any ideas?